# PHP jQuery json_encode

Tags: php, jquery, json

**PHP**

```
$results[] = array(
    'response' => $response
);
echo json_encode($results);
```

Using the above returns to my jQuery the following `data`

**Part of .ajax()**

```
success:function(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

Outputs

```
 [{"response":0}]
```

How could I change `console.log(data)` to pick the value of `response`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you set `datatype: "json"` in the [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call, the `data` object you get, contains the already parsed JSON. So you can access it like any other JavaScript object.

```
console.log( data[0].response );
```

Otherwise you might have to parse it first. ( This can happen, when the returned MIME type is wrong.)

```
data = JSON.parse( data );
console.log( data[0].response );
```

Citing the respective part of the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> **dataType**
>
> If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string).

Comment: @Beardy Is the output really like shown above or is it `"[{"response":0}]"`?

Comment: As I put it from being copied and pasted from Console.log

Comment: @Beardy Extended my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**1)**

```
console.log(data[0].response)
```

**2)**

```
for(var i in data){
  console.log(data[i].response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
success:function(data){
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(data[0].response);
}
```